# Problems in understanding segmentation (Trying to write a simple OS)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, memory-segmentation

Im trying to learn low level stuff so I thought that maybe learning how an OS works is going to be the best choice and I started learning from:
https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial

This are the codes:

main.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]
mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp
mov bx,0x1000
mov dh,1
call disk_load
call switch_to_pm

%include "print.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"
%include "32print.asm"
%include "32switch.asm"
%include "disk_func.asm"

[bits 32]
BEGIN_PM:
mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
mov eax,0
mov ch,1
mov cl,0
call print_string
mov ch,0
call print_string
mov ebx,MSG_LOADED_Kernel
mov eax,30
mov cl,1
mov ch,0
call print_string
jmp 0x1000

MSG_PROT_MODE db "Test White ... ",0
MSG_LOADED_Kernel db " Test Red ... ",0
; bootsector
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

test_load:
mov ebx,MSG_PROMPT
sub ebx,test_load
add ebx,0x1000
mov cl,2
mov ch,0
mov eax,58
call CODE_SEG:print_string
jmp $

MSG_PROMPT db "Test Green ... ",0
times 512-($-test_load) db 0
```

print.asm

```
print:
pusha
mov ah,0x0e
start:
mov al,[bx]
cmp al,0
je done
int 0x10
add bx,1
jmp start
done:
popa
ret
```

disk_func.asm

```
disk_load:
pusha
mov ah,0x02 ;<= Read
mov al,dh ;<= Sectors to read
mov cl,0x02 ;<= Sector
mov ch,0x00 ;<= Cylinder
push edx
mov dh,0x00 ;<= Head number
int 0x13
pop edx
jc disk_error
cmp al, dh
jne sectors_error
popa
ret
disk_error:
mov ecx, DISK_ERROR
call print
mov dh, ah
jmp disk_loop

sectors_error:
mov ecx, SECTORS_ERROR
call print

disk_loop:
jmp $

DISK_ERROR:
db "Disk read error", 0

SECTORS_ERROR:
db "Incorrect number of sectors read", 0
```

gdt.asm

```
gdt_start:
dd 0x0
dd 0x0
;8 null bytes

; GDT for code segment. base = 0x00000000, length = 0xfffff
gdt_code:
dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
gdt_data:
dw 0xffff
dw 0x0
db 0x0
db 10010010b
db 11001111b
db 0x0

gdt_end:
gdt_desc:
dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit)
dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)


CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

32switch.asm

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:
cli
lgdt [gdt_desc]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x1
mov cr0, eax
jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

[bits 32]
init_pm:
mov ax, DATA_SEG
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

mov ebp, 0x90000
mov esp, ebp

call BEGIN_PM
```

32print.asm

```
[bits 32]

VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f
RED_ON_BLACK equ 0x0c
GREEN_ON_BLACK equ 0x0a

print_string:
pusha
cmp cl,1
je skip_print32_red
cmp cl,2
je skip_print32_red
mov cl,0
skip_print32_red:
mov edx, VIDEO_MEMORY
add edx,eax
cmp ch,1
je clear_scrn

print_string_loop:
mov al, [ebx] ; [ebx] is the address of our character
print32_color:
cmp cl,1
je print_with_red
cmp cl,2
je print_with_green
mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK
jmp print32_skip_red
print_with_red:
mov ah, RED_ON_BLACK
jmp print32_skip_red
print_with_green:
mov ah, GREEN_ON_BLACK
print32_skip_red:
cmp al, 0 ; check if end of string
je print_string_done
mov [edx], ax ; store character + attribute in video memory
add ebx, 1 ; next char
add edx, 2 ; next video memory position
jmp print_string_loop
print_string_done:
popa
ret

clear_scrn:
mov al, 0x20
mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK
mov [edx], ax ; store character + attribute in video memory
add edx, 2 ; next video memory position
cmp edx, 0xb8492
je print_string_done
jmp clear_scrn

make_32print_red:
mov cl, 1
jmp print32_color
```

In the 32switch.asm file I understand that because init_pm starts with [bits 32] and uses 32bit registers the jump to it needs to have CODE_SEG because CODE_SEG enables 32 bit but then I dont understand why it doesnt need to call BEGIN_PM with CODE_SEG because BEGIN_PM also uses 32bit registers. also calls to print_string in BEGIN_PM and jumping to test_load dont need CODE_SEG too but in test_load it is necessary to use CODE_SEG for calling print_string otherwise it will not do anything

"test_load is going to be read from hdd to memory and jump to 0x1000 in BEGIN_PM is the jump to test_load"

It really confuses me can someone explain to me why is it needed in those places and not needed in others?
and also why calling print string from test_load requires CODE_SEG but calling it from BEGIN_PM doesnt?

Im using nasm for assembling and qemu for running the binary

Im new to assembly and low level stuff so I may have understood everything wrong

EDIT:
I was trying to solve it somehow and understand it and I found that in test_load
if I do

```
mov edx,print_string
call edx
```

it works but

```
call print_string
```

doesnt

Comment: You can use 32 bit registers in real mode too, if your cpu has them. The mode switch is changing memory management and the default operand size.

Comment: `CODE_SEG` doesn't "enable 32 bit mode" it's just a placeholder for `gdt_code - gdt_start`, i.e. it's an offset for where your code starts (I think..)  You never jump to test_load, so not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @JeffUK : `With `CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start`, `CODE_SEL` will be used as a selector into the _GDT_ that points to a descriptor entry that is used to describe an executable area of memory (along with other attributes)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out
because both test_load and print are assembled together NASM compiles them as if they are going to remain like that while executed but test_load is actually going to be read from hdd and put inside memory at 0x1000 so their distance will differ from what NASM thought
when I do

```
call print_string
```

and NASM assembles it , it uses this

```
e8 21 fe ff ff          call   0xfffffe26
```

fffffe26 stands for -474 the distance from call to print_string which would work completely normal if they were put inside the memory exactly in the way they where written
but since test_load is loaded at 0x1000 it should be (-1000+512)+(-474) so

```
call print_string
```

will not work

The reason why

```
mov edx
call edx
```

works is because its calling the address itself and it doesnt care about the distance anymore
its the same with the one with CODE_SEG, because it considers that as a far jump it calls the address without using the distance